# Is there any advantage of RC over R6?

Tags: r, r6, reference-class

I have some experience with [R6 classes](https://r6.r-lib.org/). They are powerful, with a lot of great tools under the hood.
The documentation is [amazing](https://r6.r-lib.org/articles/Introduction.html), the interface is clean, and the created classes have just the amount of methods that one requires. The option to set methods and fields as private makes it possible.

I just checked [Reference Classes](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/methods/html/refClass.html), often shortened as just `RC` from the `methods` package. Their interface is similar, but feels more complex than `R6`. They appear to have a smaller number of features (no private fields/methods). By default, `RC` creates a huge amount of methods for the objects (checked by `instance$<tab><tab>` in the console).

For instance, `RC` classes won't initialize methods immediately, so they are not available when you type `instance$<tab><tab>` (but available for call), they create `.->x` for *every* field `x` in addition to `rf$x`, and they have general getter `rf$field("x")`. All this makes the interface quite busy when you have multiple fields.

`R6` classes have a clone method. `RC` classes a copy method, but is not shown initially (only when you try to call it?), which makes the whole interface confusing.

On top of that, `RC` classes require much more memory compared to the `R6` classes (according to `R6` authors [here](https://r6.r-lib.org/articles/Performance.html)).

Is there *any* advantage to the `RC` classes besides being included in base R?

Comment: Could you give relevant links (e.g. [here](https://r6.r-lib.org/articles/Introduction.html), [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html#rc)) for those not familiar?

Comment: @BenBolker Links added

Comment: Doesn't the `R6` documentation list a number of reasons the developers created it in the first place?   I would have thought that they only did things to make code work better/faster/stronger  ( :-)  ) .     That said, the obvious reason **not** to use `R6` is to avoid requiring said library when usage advantages are minimal.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Yes, while `RC` are built with `S4`, which makes them quite bit more complex `R6` are essentially just a convenient wrapper for environments with some extra behaviour and `S3` semantics. If you compare the code of R6 and RC, R6 is _so_ much simpler. It is honestly really smart. Basically R6 is extension of this concept: https://r6.r-lib.org/articles/Performance.html#environment-created-by-a-function-call-without-class-attribute.

Comment: So the only advantage of `RC` seems to be no non-base dependencies (but see previous link, you can get a lot with a simple function call environment if you don't need formalism) and also some strong typing (i.e., you set slots to be of a certain type)